# zsh is not completing multiple commands with up arrow

Tags: zsh, command-history

Im using zsh with this plugin: `zsh-history-substring-search`

When I type for example `sudo pacman <UPArrow>` It show some commands starting with `sudo pacman`, but it also show command starting only with sudo, but without pacman like: 
`sudo kill 11064`
`sudo fdisk /dev/sda`
So the autocompletions ignores second command.

How to set zsh-history-substring-search plugin to work with multiple commands?

Comment: I dont mean autocompletion, I am talking about items from history which are displayed using `[↑]` , they should be filtered by whole string which I typed  (for ex. `sudo pacman`, should show commands from history which contains sudo pacman <something> and not only sudo <something>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get what you are looking for without needing a plugin.  Based on this [Unix Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100860/149720), simply add the following to your `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward
```

You might need to adjust the keycodes provided to `bindkey` - the linked answer provides more details.

EDIT:

Using the ZLE widgets mentioned in this [blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/jpj_6q/zsh-better-history-searching-with-arrow-keys) would probably be superior, because for multiline buffers they move up or down within the buffer; while for a single line they perform the same as `history-beginning-search-backward` and `-forward`:

```
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search
```